# RegEx for retrieving a score number from a JSON

Tags: regex, hive, apache-spark-sql, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need to extract the float number after score.

```
{"reason_desc":
   {
    "score":"0.1",
    "numOfIndicatrix":"0",
    "indicatrix":[]},
    "success":true,
    "id":"1555039965661065S427A2DCF5787920"
}
```

I expect the output of 0.1 or any number enclosed by "".

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. Everyone that posts here can say *Some help needed*, and the tags say that it's about Hive, Apache Spark and regex. Removing that non-meaningful information from your title makes it say nothing at all. Your title should describe a specific problem or ask a specific question in a way that will have meaning to future readers here scanning through a list of search results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/zygPtm/1/) might help you to get `0.1`. It divides the target line into two groups, where the second group (`$2`) returns your desired float numbers:

```
("score":")([0-9\.\,]+)
```

[image: RegEx]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to parse JSON using regexp in Hive, it has embedded functions for the same:

```
with your_table as (--use your table instead of this
select '{"reason_desc":
   {
    "score":"0.1",
    "numOfIndicatrix":"0",
    "indicatrix":[]},
    "success":true,
    "id":"1555039965661065S427A2DCF5787920"
}' as json_col
)

select get_json_object(t.json_col,'$.reason_desc.score') as score
  from your_table t
```

Result:

```
0.1
```

See also: [json_tuple](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-json_tuple)